# HttpWebResponse Stream reading in uneven chunks

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, streaming, httpwebrequest

I am using the stream from `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()` to read data from a streaming web API. I use `Begin`/`EndRead` on the stream with a buffer of 65K bytes. I can see that data is being returned in the following pattern:

```
16383 bytes read.
1 bytes read.
16383 bytes read.
1 bytes read.
16383 bytes read.
1 bytes read.
etc...
```

Obviously the 1 byte reads introduce a lot of inefficiency in the process, and the buffer size I provide is large enough to fit 16384 bytes or more. Is there anything I can do as a client to improve this or is simply up to the server how it's streaming data to me?

The reader code is basically:

```
var buffer = new byte[65536];
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
    while (true) {
        var bytesRead = await AsyncRead(stream.BeginRead, stream.EndRead, buffer);
        Console.WriteLine($"{bytesRead} bytes read.");
        // do something with the bytes
    }
}
```

where AsyncRead just calls `BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, callback, null)`, then `EndRead` in the callback and returns the return value of `EndRead`.

BTW this is on .NET 4.0, no HttpClient.

Comment: I am not sure if the 1 byte reduces efficiency that much since the http connection should stay open and the data transfer is probably a lot slower than the cpu overhead to read that byte. Nevertheless, it is strange behaviour. Can you post the relevant pieces of the reader code?

Comment: @Stefan, sure, it's actually F# using a different async implementation but I've translated. There's nothing special going on in the async code it just passes parameters and return values as-is.

Comment: Wild guesses: compression or encryption is the culprit.  Try turning compression off (or on) on the `HttpWebRequest`.  Likewise, see if the behavior is the same on an `http` vs. an `https` connection.  I believe TLS sends data in 2^14 byte-sized chunks (i.e. 16384 bytes).

Comment: @ChrisR.Timmons I'm using HTTPS indeed; that's a requirement though, no way around it. Will check if enabling compression helps, thanks.

Comment: Did you fiddler your http traffic to see what's coming with 1 byte data?

Answer (score -1):

What exactly are you trying to achieve by sending the HTTPWebRequest to the target server?

Are you trying to read a live response from the server after asking the server for data or initializing a request between your client application and the target server? If you are try to send an HTTPWepRequest and an HTTPWebResponse to the target server then convert the response given from the server to a stream then use System.IO.StreamReader to read the in-coming stream!

Then just to be on the safe side convert the stream that was read by the System.IO.StreamReader method into UTF-8 if that is your overall goal!

After converting to UTF-8 you can now print the output stream into a string value which you can output to console or wherever you want to send the output string!

I hope this is what you wanted if not then I have been essentially useless! :P

Comment: How is reading through a StreamReader supposed to help with my issue?
"What exactly are you trying to achieve by sending the HTTPWebRequest to the target server?" - to obtain data from a streaming web API, as stated.

Comment: Well if your trying to read data that was sent by the server then you want to do that I just presented an option in case it was what you needed!

Comment: I am reading data from the server just fine! I'm afraid you didn't understand the question, but thanks anyway.